# sum and join the column correctly

Tags: mysql, join, sum

database

loan

```
[id_loan] [id_customer] [qty_loan][amount] 
  1            1             2       8 
  2            1             1       4 
  3            2             3      12 
  4            1             1       4
```

payment

```
[id_pay] [id_customer] [qty_pay] [pay]
  1            1           1       4 
  2            1           2       8 
  3            2           2       8 
  4            2           1       4
```

i want to join and then get sum result but the result was wrong here is the sql code

```
SELECT
     SUM(qty_loan) as qty_loan,SUM(amount) as amount ,SUM(qty_pay) as qty_pay,SUM(pay) as pay  
    FROM loan JOIN payment ON loan.id_customer = payment.id_customer 
    WHERE loan.id_customer='1'
```

Comment: This is "join multiplying". You must aggregate each separate table in separate subqueries then join them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we have 2 records in both tables the JOIN finds 4 matches and each value is duplicated.
We can query one of the tables in a sub-query, grouped by id_customer, to avoid this problem.

> ```
> SELECT
>   l.id_customer,
>   qty_loan,
>   amount ,
>   SUM(qty_pay) as qty_pay,
>   SUM(pay) as pay  
> FROM (SELECT 
>         id_customer,
>         SUM(qty_loan) as qty_loan,
>         SUM(amount) as amount 
>         FROM loan 
>         GROUP BY id_customer) l
> LEFT JOIN payment 
> ON l.id_customer = payment.id_customer 
> /*-WHERE loan.id_customer='1'*/
> GROUP BY 
>   l.id_customer,  
>   qty_loan,
>   amount ;
> ```
>
> ```
> id_customer | qty_loan | amount | qty_pay | pay
> ----------: | -------: | -----: | ------: | --:
>           1 |        4 |     16 |       3 |  12
>           2 |        3 |     12 |       3 |  12
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=a7e363b53d6081da1d08abc78e7c67a3)*

Comment: Incomplete GROUP BY... it is safe to expand GROUP BY expression for the query validity. Also none guarantees that any particular `id_customer` is present in both tables - if not then the output will be partial.

Comment: @Akina thank you - it's strange that the query ran OK in dbFiddle with only one of 3 static fields in the group by. I've modified and added `LEFT JOIN` so that we will get loans where no payments have been made. (presumably no clients will make repayments if they don't have loans!)

Comment: *it's strange that the query ran OK in dbFiddle with only one of 3 static fields in the group by.* This is MySQL extension - the column used in GROUP BY is also used in GROUP BY in the subquery, this guarantees uniqueness of this column value, and server agrees with another columns skipping. But in general you'd disable ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY for such query to be executed without error.